# How to reduce the space between the hat of overset and the symbol?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, accents

I would like to place the `\rightharpoonup` on r and get them closer.
I had tried the `\overset` and `\Rvector` package.
But the spacing of the former is too much. And the latter performs bad when placing
in smaller font size. I provide the code as follow:

```
 \documentclass[titlepage]{article}
 \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 \[\mathbf{e}_{\overset{\rightharpoonup}{r}}\]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please read [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-not-too-dirty offering: a macro called `\harp`. It assumes it'll be used in subscript and superscript positions only. For now, it only works with letters that *do not* have an ascender part. I.e., don't use if with letters such as b, d, f, h, etc. (If you do need to use the macro with such letters, you'll need to tweak the argument of the `\raise` macro.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand\harp[1]{\mathstrut\mkern2.5mu#1\mkern-11mu\raise0.6ex%
  \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\rightharpoonup$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{e}_{\overset{\rightharpoonup}{r}}
\text{ vs.\ }
\mathbf{e}_{\harp{r}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two orders of problems:

1. the distance from the arrow to the symbol is too big;
2. in subscripts or superscripts, the arrow is too wide.

Here's a solution for both.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\harp}[1]{\mathpalette\harpoonvec{#1}}
\newcommand{\harpvecsign}{\scriptscriptstyle\rightharpoonup}
\newcommand{\harpoonvec}[2]{%
  \ifx\displaystyle#1\doalign{$\harpvecsign$}{#1#2}\fi
  \ifx\textstyle#1\doalign{$\harpvecsign$}{#1#2}\fi
  \ifx\scriptstyle#1\doalign{\scalebox{.6}[.9]{$\harpvecsign$}}{#1#2}\fi
  \ifx\scriptscriptstyle#1\doalign{\scalebox{.5}[.8]{$\harpvecsign$}}{#1#2}\fi
}
\newcommand{\doalign}[2]{%
 {\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr#1\cr$#2$\cr}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{e}_{\harp{r}_{\harp{r}}}  \harp{\mathbf{g}} \harp{A}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `accents` package. The difference of vertical spacing with respect to the O.P. method with `\overset` is null in `scriptscriptstyle`, slight  in `\scriptstyle` and more important in `\textstyle`. Otherwise the placement is different :

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{accents}
 \newcommand*\harp[1]{\mkern2mu\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}\mkern2mu}%

 \begin{document}

        \[ \begin{array}{cc}
        \texttt{\small\textbackslash mathaccent: } & \texttt{\small\textbackslash overset: }\\
        \mathbf{e}_{\scriptscriptstyle\harp r} & \mathbf{e}_{\scriptscriptstyle\overset{\rightharpoonup}{r}} \\[2pt]          
       \mathbf{e}_{\harp r} &   \mathbf{e}_{\overset{\rightharpoonup}{r}} \\[4pt]  
       \harp{\mathbf g } &  \overset{\rightharpoonup}{\mathbf g}
       \end{array} \]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The vertical space between the harpoon and the letter seems no smaller (and possibly even a bit larger) in your code as is already the case with the OP's code.

Comment: It is slightly smaller in `scriptstyle`(by 0.4pt), equal in `scriptscriptstyle` and noticeably smaller in `textstyle` (by 1.4pt). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Macros from the `stackengine` package allow one to set the vertical stacking gap.  Compare items 1 vs. 2 and/or items 3 vs. 4, and/or 5 vs. 6 for a demonstration of changing the stacking gap.  In addition, the appearance will also be affected by what is considered the baseline of the subscipt.  In 1, 2, the baseline is between the "r" and the harpoon; in 3, 4, the "r" is the baseline, whereas in 5, 6, the "harpoon" is the baseline.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{e}_{\stackanchor[-.5pt]{\scriptscriptstyle \rightharpoonup}{\scriptstyle r}}
\mathbf{e}_{\stackanchor[0pt]{\scriptscriptstyle \rightharpoonup}{\scriptstyle r}}
~
\mathbf{e}_{\stackon[-.5pt]{\scriptstyle r}{\scriptscriptstyle \rightharpoonup}}
\mathbf{e}_{\stackon[0pt]{\scriptstyle r}{\scriptscriptstyle \rightharpoonup}}
~
\mathbf{e}_{\stackunder[-.5pt]{\scriptscriptstyle \rightharpoonup}{\scriptstyle r}}
\mathbf{e}_{\stackunder[0pt]{\scriptscriptstyle \rightharpoonup}{\scriptstyle r}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]